# SQL - Update 2 columns splitting another column which is separated with undescore

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 columns the 3 are empty and the third contains data as below
[image]

I want to update name_id with the numbers before the underscore and the product_id column with the number after the underscore. I am using sql developer.
I tried several solution but i didn't find how can i separate them based on the underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Using the base string functions we can try:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET name_id = SUBSTR(nameid_p, 1, INSTR(nameid_p, '_') - 1),
    product_id = SUBSTR(nameid_p, INSTR(nameid_p, '_') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option might be using regular expressions.

Before:

```
SQL> select * from test;

NAMEID_P   NAME_ID    PRODUCT_ID
---------- ---------- ----------
123_456
653_857
5633_85
```

Update; the first one takes digits anchored to the beginning of `nameid_p`, while the second one anchors to the end of the string:

```
SQL> update test set
  2    name_id = regexp_substr(nameid_p, '^\d+'),
  3    product_id = regexp_substr(nameid_p, '\d+$');

3 rows updated.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from test;

NAMEID_P   NAME_ID    PRODUCT_ID
---------- ---------- ----------
123_456    123        456
653_857    653        857
5633_85    5633       85

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can basically `[^_]` pattern in order to split those string values along with `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` function as option such as

```sql
UPDATE t --> your table
   SET name_id = REGEXP_SUBSTR(nameid_p,'[^_]+'),
       product_id = REGEXP_SUBSTR(nameid_p,'[^_]+$')
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=10afaeb2c79569cf04d5f7cb5b7ae648)</kbd>

No need to apply `TO_NUMBER()` conversion to the splitted parts during the Update operation, since already Oracle implicitly does this.